# DateTimepicker displaying upwards and getting cut off. How to display downwards

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

Hi when I click on my datetimepicker it pop ups upwards and gets cut off in the heading. What can I do to this?

And I just want to know. Sometimes my picker changes display in Firefox but works in Chrome. Is this normal?

[image: Getting cut off]

Script code

```
    $(function () {
        $('.searchDate').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy/mm/dd",

            todayBtn: "linked",

            autoclose: true

        });

    })
```

Comment: Probably a css issue

Comment: I think in properties you have a property called popup position, set it to bottom

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
Whatever position you have to set you can mention it in beforeShow function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".searchDate").datepicker(
 {
 beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
     inst.dpDiv.css({ marginTop: -input.offsetHeight + 'px', marginLeft:input.offsetWidth + 'px' });
 },
 format: "yyyy/mm/dd",

 todayBtn: "linked",

 autoclose: true

 });
});
```

check this fiddle -> https://fiddle.jshell.net/sbLbwm6a/

Comment: check this, http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Make-jQuery-datepicker-to-popup-in-different-positions-995.php

Comment: hey i think ur grid is blocking it to come down, once try without grid , does any changes happen...